# Understanding the development pattern for Node js app with Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, design-patterns, mongoose

I have been devoting a lot of hours to understand how to write a node js app with Typescript using all possible reusability components in typescript to make this (existing app in JS) code extensive app to be more precise and easy to maintain. Lately I came across [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Application-Example-NodeJS-d632ee2d) repository. It's basically explaining the clean way of doing CRUD operations using mongoose. I'd like to have a similar approach. But `Business` under the `App` directory is not understandable. How to drive this project? Please help in understanding the structure, the approach & Is it worth doing it this way?
If there exists some other easy yet robust way of starting things up, do mention them as well. Thanks.

PS: I know its mentioned about the patterns and principle used:

- Generic Repository Pattern
- Singleton Pattern
- Multi-layer Architecture Pattern

Still no luck, as far as the understanding goes.

Comment: have you got answer to this question?

Comment: No, still haven't found any clear explanation!!